# Executing two methods from map

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

I have following code:

```
require "ostruct"
arguments = [OpenStruct.new({:name=>"ABCD",    :city => "Delhi"}), 
             OpenStruct.new({:name=>"Awesome", :city => "Bhiwandi"}),
             OpenStruct.new({:name=>"good",    :city => "Chandigarh"})]
arguments.map(&:name)
#results ["ABCD", "Awesome", "good"]
```

but what I want is :

```
[["ABCD", "Delhi"], ["Awesome", "Bhiwandi"], ["good", "Chandigarh"]]
```

I can get this by:

```
 arguments.map(&:name).zip(arguments.map(&:city))
```

but, is there some more elegant way to do it, something like `arguments.map(&[:name, :city]).`?

Comment: Do you have to use OpenStruct?

Comment: I just used it for posing the question, in actual, my arguments is an array of active record relations.

Comment: What is `"Ostruct"`? It doesn't seem to be a standard library, nor a gem. When introducing a non-standard one, you need to explain it.

Comment: @sawa You can't recognize a simple typo? Maybe you could try the obvious "did you mean `require 'ostruct'` where you `require 'Ostruct'`?"

Comment: OpenStruct is a data structure, similar to a Hash, more details [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). corrected this in question  in require.

Comment: @saurabh No, that is a different library.

Comment: @saurabh It is bad idea and too slow,..but still for you `arguments.map(&->(o){ [o.name, o.city] }`

Comment: @saurabh  OR, `arguments.map(&->(o, ar = %i(name city)){ ar.map { |sym| o.send(sym)} })` .. None of them looks good  :-)

Comment: Please consider selecting the answer you found most helpful, unless, of course, none met your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think is it more elegant or not, but: `arguments.map { |a| [a[:name], a[:city]] }`

You should post such question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is better, however I was looking, if I can do something of the sort:  arguments.map(&[:name, :city]).

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
arguments.map { |o| [o.name, o.city] }
  #=> [["ABCD", "Delhi"], ["Awesome", "Bhiwandi"], ["good", "Chandigarh"]]
```